# What's the best way to go about having multiple users as inputs in a command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So, I want to create a command that uses multiple user pings as input. Here's what I have so far:

```js
let mentionedUser = msg.mentions.users.first();

if (mentionedUser === msg.author)
 return msg.channel.send(
  `***${msg.author.username}** kisses... themselves? ~~Impressive.~~`
 );
else return msg.channel.send('Oi! You gotta actually ping a member!');

if (parameters) {
 var embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#06FBFE')
  .setDescription(
   `**${msg.author.username}** kisses **${mentionedUser.username}**`
  );
 msg.channel.send(embed1);
} else return msg.channel.send('Please give me a user to kiss! :3');
```

How should I got about using multiple mentions without creating `undefined` variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Collection.map()` and `Array.prototype.join()` to make use of multiple mentions:

```js
.setDescription(
 `**${msg.author.username}** kisses **${message.mentions.users
  .map((user) => user.username)
  .join(', ')}**`
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to do a bit of tweaking but, it worked like a charm!